# Ok, we can have private identifiers in javascript, but what about protected ones?

Tags: javascript, visibility, protected

Simple as that, can we emulate the "protected" visibility in Javascript somehow?

Comment: I think the main point is, in a language like JavaScript you can put the barrier there ... but it is like sandbags ... it might not stop the water soaking your carpet :P

Comment: I believe callee is deprecated, and that's what people seem to be relying on to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Do this:

```
/* Note: Do not break/touch this object */
...code...
```

Or a bit of google found this on the first page:

http://blog.blanquera.com/2009/03/javascript-protected-methods-and.html

Comment: What this guy is doing is just ducktyping to see if he's 'this' has the same method as the calling function... it cannot guarantee that's the same guy who's calling.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I don't think that this way you can really protect your 'protected' stuff :P

Comment: @Pablo, I agree totally ... but if you want that behavior as concrete semantics then JS isn't the language you want :P

Answer (score 2):

[Sure](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-inject-protected-methods-in.html) you can.  Here's another [example](http://blog.blanquera.com/2009/03/javascript-protected-methods-and.html).

Answer (score 1):

What could that possibly mean?  You don't have *classes*.

I suppose you could analyze `caller` to determine whether it meets some set of criteria for being permitted to call a method.  This will be hideously inefficient and your criteria will always be spoofable.

Comment: Not exactly true.  In Javascript _everything_ is an object.  You define classes using an active syntax, instead of a passive one.  Composition vs. declaration.

Comment: @Christopher ... You are wrong, just because it is prototypical doesnt mean the prototypes are classes! Are they also interfaces?

Comment: Well, okay.  But what I mean is that you don't have a namespace of entity categorizations to which an object can be known to belong or not belong, which is what protected visibility normally keys on.  You can't tell an inheritor from something that wants to look like an inheritor.

Comment: Still, without proper classes we can have the concept of private members using JS Variable scoping tho

Comment: I think languages that leave the semantics out and allow implementations (like decorators and such) are cool. Just a pain in the arse when you need a 'standard' effect.

Answer (score 1):

There's an interesting pattern worth mentioning here: a JavaScript contructor function may return any object (not necesserily *this*). One could create a constructor function, that returns a proxy object, that contains proxy methods to the "real" methods of the "real" instance object. This may sound complicated, but it is not; here is a code snippet:

```
var MyClass = function() {
    var instanceObj = this;
    var proxyObj = {
        myPublicMethod: function() {
            return instanceObj.myPublicMethod.apply(instanceObj, arguments);
        }
    }
    return proxyObj;
};
MyClass.prototype = {
    _myPrivateMethod: function() {
        ...
    },
    myPublicMethod: function() {
        ...
    }
};
```

The nice thing is that the proxy creation can be automated, if we define a convention for naming the protected methods. I created a little library that does exactly this: http://idya.github.com/oolib/